# How to boot Ubuntu after installing Windows using BootCamp

Tags: boot, windows, macbook-pro

I have had the need to create a working Ubuntu 64-bit and Windows 7 pro 64-bit dual booting system of late and decided my  Macbook Pro 8.2 15". I had previously removed the Mac OS X from it as it was having issues so I formatted the whole HD and had Windows 7 running on it without troubles (bootcamp 4, 5, 5.1).

I ended up making a mistake and wiping everything during the installation of the Ubuntu partition (after shrinking the Windows one and partitioning it... I didn't realize that the "Erase and Install Ubuntu" toggle performed the erase IMMEDIATELY!)

After installing successfully Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit I installed Windows 7 in the remaining unpartitioned space. Once done so upon boot the computer boots only in W7 and the Startup Manager accessed from holding the alt / option key upon booting only recognizes the presence of one hard drive and not the various bootable partition. When clicked it will simply boot in Windows.

Now I understand this is because windows does not recognize `ext4` and that I should boot in the linux (GRUB?) partition as it can deal with both ext4 and NTFS, however the Startup Manager also doesn't recognize the two boot partitions which means I am stuck booting in windows 7 at this moment.

This [guides](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation#Detailed_How-To) states I would need to get Ubuntu to EFI-boot using `rEFInd` which would be installed through the Mac partition, though the [article](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/) says it was a necessary thing for 32-bit; is it still for 64-bit as it was running great?

What would you recommend doing to achieve the dual boot? Should I install a temp version of OSX to follow the guide?

These were the partitions I made when installing Ubuntu, do I need other ones?

1. A reserved for bios 1 MB
2. swap 6 GB
3. / 100 GB ext4
4. /media/shared 30 GB fat32 (there was no ntfs in the list strangely enough)
5. The rest was left unpartitioned

I didn't make a /home partition.

The installation went perfectly for Ubuntu. It started up wonderfully and working great. I proceeded to install windows and had to create the windows partition in the shared partition by extending it to 300 GB because it wouldn't allow me to create one in the remaining free allocated space (commands grayed out)

Comment: About your partitions: if it works that's fine, but next time (if you decide to make a new installation) I'd recommend that /home partition instead of /swap. Actually, you don't need the /swap partition (in general) at all, if you have 2+ GB RAM - I guess you do... But you should have (it's adviced) the /home partition, as 'working directory'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try out this software EasyBCD on windows. Its a recommendation only but it helped me when I faced the same situation as yours.

After that you might want to run boot - repair when you get to boot in Ubuntu and then remove EasyBCD.

Here are the detailed instructions:

1. Download EasyBCD from [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml)
2. Install EasyBCD in your Windows Partition.
3. Now, run EasyBCD as an administrator.
4. Next, click on "Add New Entry".

   [image: Add New Entry]
5. Next, Click on 'Linux/BSD" under "Operating Systems" then select "GRUB 2" under "Type:", type a name according to your choice and click "Add Entry".

   [image: Add Entry]
6. Now, click on "Edit Boot Menu".

   [image: Edit Boot Menu]
7. Now, according to your OS priority select your OS and press the up button and set it "Default - Yes" by ticking in the appropriate box.

   [image: Modify Menu Entries]

And finally "Save Settings" and reboot. You will get the menu for your linux and on pressing enter you will get the GRUB menu to your linux OS.

Comment: I will look into it immediately I am surprised someone had such a similar issue. Thank you will keep you posted

Comment: OK. Hope it works for you too. :-)

Comment: Could you kindly outline what you did once you installed it so that I may follow your "trodden path" so to speak please :)

Comment: Do you see an Add New Entry option there?

Comment: Yep I do see it indeed

Comment: Click on that and you will see a tabbed menu.

Comment: There click on Linux, then choose your boot menu as GRUB 2. Its GRUB(legacy) BY DEFAULT. Then click save settings.

Comment: Ah so this adds the entry for the windows to recognise does it? Thank you

Comment: If you are confused would you like some screenshots?

Comment: Well I think your answer has all to gain from adding them I do understand myself how to proceed with your instructions thus far

Comment: OK, just ask when you need one. :-)

Comment: Which partition should I be pointing EasyBCD to for it to start up in ubuntu? Cause it gives me a blank screen when i direct it to the / one

Comment: You don't have to point to any particular partition. Just select the whole hardrive and it will find the ubuntu partition itself.

Comment: Ok I got it to find it by using the GRUB 2 rather than legacy option as the grub legacy would fail to find anything.

Comment: Yup that’s why i recommended grub2 above. So, is it working?

Comment: Ah yes, my poor reading skills. It is working great at this time, thank you for this solution :) I appreciate wholeheartedly for the help too!

Comment: Welcome. Glad it worked for you too.

Comment: Could you write the exact instructions about how to use EasyBSD to fix the problem?

Comment: Braiam I edited the answer with screenshots and explained as to how to do it.